# Cannot get duplication of screens to work with mini display between iMac & Macbook

Tags: command-line, imac, screen, displayport

Have an iMac 21", 2.5, Mid 2011 and a MacBook Pro Mid 2012 and I just bought a Mini display to connect them through the Thunderbolt. I cannot see that they are connected or the choice to connect it in the screen logo in the menu bar. <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> doesn't work.

Any idea whats wrong? how can I get the option to have them connected, not for data, just sound and image?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to use a [Thunderbolt Cable](http://radnex.us/Apple-Thunderbolt-Cable-1M) to use your iMac in [Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592).  From Apple's website:

[image]

From your original question, you mention that you purchased a "mini display" which I can only deduce is that you meant that you bought a "mini Display Port cable."  If this is in fact the case, it's the wrong cable; which is why it's not working.